# Python three numpy arrays, combine columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have three arrays:

```
a = array([1,2,3,4])
b = array([5,6,7,8])
c = array([9,10,11,12])
```

I would like a single array:

```
result = array([1,5,9],
               [2,6,10],
               [3,7,11],
               [4,8,12])
```

i.e. take the first column of every array and make it as the first row and so on.
I know it might sound trivial, but have been scratching my head.

Comment: Besides stacking as in the linked answer, you need to transpose the result to obtain the shape you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use the numpy module:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([5,6,7,8])
c = np.array([9,10,11,12])

result = np.stack((a,b,c), axis = 1) # axis = 1 transposes the stacked matrix

print(result)
```

The code above gives the following output:

```
[[ 1  5  9]
 [ 2  6 10]
 [ 3  7 11]
 [ 4  8 12]]
```

Which is what you wanted.